# Algorithm for searching grid in different direction

Tags: algorithm, grid, search

Today a work mate posed a question to me.
Given a grid of characters and a list of words one would have to find every occurrence of that word in the grid both horizontally, vertically and diagonally.

The solution we came up with works and does the trick but I am interested to see how other peoples minds tick.

Comment: Forwards and Backwards matches count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert each word in the list in a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), or [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) or any dictionary.

Now, for each position in your grid, go horizontally, vertically and diagonally and see if you get matches in the dictionary. This should give you `O(N^3)` worst case complexity, where `N` is the size of the grid. Otherwise it's `O(N^2*averageWordLength)` I think.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `O(N*maxWordLength)`?  Each letter only needs to be checked for being the start of a word of length 1, 2, 3, ..., maxWordLength.

Comment: A hash table would be a poor choice compared to a trie.  With the trie, once you don't get any matches for a string of length k you can stop.  With a hash table you can't stop until you've tried all strings of length n (n is the distance from your char to the edge).  For example, let's say you have the row (INTABCDE).  The word INTEGER is in your dictionary.  With the trie, you first try I, which is not in the dictionary but is a valid path.  You continue until A, and you are no longer on a valid path.  You can't do that with a hash table, so you would be forced to hash all possible strings.

Comment: @BlueRaja - that's what I said too actually :). I meant `N` to be the size of an `N x N` grid (which therefore has `N^2` total elements). If you consider `N` to be the total number of elements in the grid, then it's `N` not `N^2`. @Niki - true.

Comment: Boyer-Moore's is a nice alg for exact string matching